# Silverstripe 4.3 Change Button in Datamodel

Tags: forms, button, action, backend, silverstripe-4

I have a Datamodel on my Silverstripe. When I want to add an object or edit on the button on the buttom says "Apply changes". I would like to change that to german. And there are several other english expression in the cms. Where can I chance that to have a complete german cms?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Non-English translations for SilverStripe are managed through [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/). If there are some German translations missing you can fix them here: http://transifex.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-versioned.

You can also override these in your project code by adding a file like this:

```
# File: app/lang/de.yml
de:
  SilverStripe\Versioned\VersionedGridFieldItemRequest:
    BUTTONAPPLYCHANGES: 'Correct German translation here...'
```

Answer (score 0):

Access your profile data (by clicking on your name on the top left or by accessing the **Security** section) and change your interface language:

[image]

This is a personal settings, i.e. every registered user can have its own locale.